# How "Data access expires" affects on reponses from webhook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Me and our team are in the process of implementation small backend providing facebook chatbot functionality, which has to be able to handle multiple fanpages attached to it.

When facebook callback arrives to webhook, we can easily recognize which fanpage it belongs to and select from db valid page access token, which we receive during process of integration of fanpage and our frontend application (integration understood as process which user logged to our application gives us permissions to his fanpage).

We decided to extend page access token that it never expires and that solves problem of repeating whole process of giving us permissions to fanpage by user (integration mentioned before).

We are wondering about "Data access expires". From our knowledge, this term is always 90 days, and it cannot be extended. How it affects on sending responses to messenger users ? Will we be able to correctly response on messages sent to webhook after this term expires ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data#data-access:

> The following permissions do not expire:
>
> - ads_read business_management
> - configure_page_transactions
> - manage_pages
> - pages_manage_cta
> - pages_manage_instant_articles
> - pages_messaging
> - pages_show_list
> - publish_pages
> - read_audience_network_insights
> - read_insights ads_management

`manage_pages` and `pages_messaging` are the only two that are necessary for your purpose, so that should cover it.