# Effect of "Data Access Expires" expiration on webhook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

this question is for Facebook developers especially those who have been using Graph API in their projects. I've set up a webhook application in a client's Facebook account to be able to fetch user comments from the pages they've been managing into the app we made. Our app also has a feature to reply and hide user comments but these features require Page Access Tokens. The tokens that we have generated from the Graph API Explorer have been converted to Long-Lived Tokens in order to not expire. However, upon debugging the access token, the "Data Access Expires" confuses me.

[image: Access Token Info]

According to their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data#data-access) and this guy's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362554/how-data-access-expires-affects-on-reponses-from-webhook), the scopes listed in the Access Token Info picture I posted should not expire. I asked this question because my use case from the post I've referenced is different, with mine using webhook for pages and no user authentication is involved. Should I still expect that the webhooks and the functionality of replying and hiding user comments are still working should the token I am using has its "Data Access Expires" expire?

Comment: _“the scopes listed in the Access Token Info picture I posted should not expire”_ - you got f.e. `email` in there as well, and that one _does_ expire. Pretty sure this is to be interpreted as, data access will expire for all permissions that _are_ affected, at the given time.

Comment: The _email_ in this scope only refers to the email of the account owner, which we didn't really use. The important ones are all _pages_ and _manage_posts_ permissions because these permissions are needed by the access token to be able to get comments from a page being managed by the account owner via webhook and for replying and hiding comments.

Comment: Doesn’t matter, it is part of the scope of the token, because that is based on the permissions the user token encompassed, that was used to generated the page token. And besides, you don’t appear to have gotten the point I was trying to make … Facebook shows the DAE timestamp there, so that you’ll know when the data access expires for those fields, that _are_ accessed by any of the permissions, that _do_ expire. I don’t see any reason to interpret that as it affecting any of the permissions, that _don’t_ expire.